# What is the essence of the error and how can it be corrected?

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, cvlib

```
import mouse
import time
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cvlib as cv
from cvlib.object_detection import draw_bbox

image = cv2.imread("cube.jpg")
box, label, count = cv.detect_common_objects(image)
output = draw_bbox(image, box, label, count)
print(label)
print(f"Количество объектов на картинке: {label.count('cube')}")

plt.imshow(output)
plt.show()
```

Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Евгений\PycharmProjects\Liga\main.py", line 9, in <module>
box, label, count = cv.detect_common_objects(image)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\Евгений\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\cvlib\object_detection.py", line 125, in detect_common_objects
net = cv2.dnn.readNet(weights_file_abs_path, config_file_abs_path)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.8.1) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\dnn\src\darknet\darknet_importer.cpp:210: error: (-212:Parsing error) Failed to open NetParameter file: C:\Users\Евгений.cvlib\object_detection\yolo\yolov3\yolov4.cfg in function 'cv::dnn::dnn4_v20230620::readNetFromDarknet'

I tried reinstalling everything

Answer (score 0):

It is probably due to your Python version: cvlib seems to be abandoned now, and it doesn't work for higher Python versions. Try 3.6. If still doesn't work, downgrade opencv to some older version.